# PAM standard macros and logging on CentOS7

Tags: centos, logging, pam

According to the `D(x)` macro defined in `pam_macros.h` (**[source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pam/pam-9/pam/libpam/include/pam/_pam_macros.h)**) and used as follows:

```
D(("Hello PAM World"));
```

Where is this log located on `CentOS7`?

Note that I am using as flag `debug` in my `pam.d` conf file.

I tried also the following command:

```
grep -rnw '/var/log/' -e "Hello Pam World"
```

But with no success.

Comment: [Linux-PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) != [OpenPAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPAM). OS X uses OpenPAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's PAM implementation for Mac OS X is perhaps not the most ideal source of information for PAM on Centos 7.

```
# yum -y install pam-devel
# rpm -ql pam-devel | grep macro
/usr/include/security/_pam_macros.h
# grep FILE `!!`
grep FILE `rpm -ql pam-devel | grep macro`
 * _PAM_LOGFILE must exist and be writable to the programs you debug.
#ifndef _PAM_LOGFILE
#define _PAM_LOGFILE "/var/run/pam-debug.log"
    FILE *logfile;
    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
    FILE *logfile;
    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
    _pam_output_debug_info(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); \
```

Also, PAM must be compiled with the `DEBUG` define for any of that code to be reached.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question... Which is the proper way to define the flag `DEBUG`? Has it to be added at compile time?

Comment: Yes, at compile time. The `gcc` or whatever lines should show a `-DDEBUG` if you've set it right for the compile. This could either be done in the RPM `*.spec` file somewhere, or via a manual build via `CFLAGS=-DDEBUG ...`